# WooCommerce: Hide Category from Product Category Widget

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I’ve usually been able to solve each of my WP demands by myself but this one proved to be a bit tricky.

The thing is, I need to hide certain categories from the Product Category Widget based on the category I’m in.

Example:
When I’m in category A, I want to show categories A, B, C, D but not E.
However, when I’m in category B, I want to show categories A, B, C, D and E as well.
Then, let’s say I’m in category C and I want to only show categories C and D.

I found the following code

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_categories_widget_args', 'woo_product_cat_widget_args' );

function woo_product_cat_widget_args( $cat_args ) {

                $cat_args['exclude'] = array('15');

                return $cat_args;

}
```

What I want to do with this code is to add multiple lines where I would define that when, for example, I open category ID 1 don’t show IDs 2,3,4. Then the next line would define what IDs not to show for ID 2, next for let’s say ID 4, and so on.

**/* EDIT**
An amazing stackoverflow user helped me by creating the code you can see in his post below. However, as we found out, the example I posted above only works for the built-in WP Product Categories Widget.

That led me to find out that the Product Categories Widget I use is custom-built with the theme I use and apparently, it uses this code to work:

```
if ( !function_exists( 'getbowtied_megamenu_output_shop_icons' )):
    /**
     * Build the layout for the "Shop Icons" type megamenu
     *
     * @param  int $theID  id of the menu item
     *
     * @return html
     */

    function getbowtied_megamenu_output_shop_icons( $theID, $cat= false) {
        if ( !GETBOWTIED_WOOCOMMERCE_IS_ACTIVE ) return;
            $cat_list = GBT_Opt::getOption('product_categories_icons_megamenu_' . $theID );
            ob_start();
            if ($cat !== true):
                $args= array( 'taxonomy' => 'product_cat','hide_empty' => 0, 'menu_order' => 'asc',  'parent' =>0, 'include' => $cat_list );
            else:
                $args= array( 'taxonomy' => 'product_cat','hide_empty' => 0, 'menu_order' => 'asc',  'parent' =>$theID, 'include' => $cat_list );
            endif;
            $cats = get_terms( $args );

            if ( is_array($cat_list)):
            $unsorted = array();
            $sorted   = array();

            foreach ($cats as $v) {
                $unsorted[$v->term_id] = $v;
            }

            foreach ($cat_list as $v) {
                if (isset($unsorted[apply_filters( 'wpml_object_id', $v, 'category', TRUE)]))
                $sorted[] = $unsorted[apply_filters( 'wpml_object_id', $v, 'category', TRUE)];
            }
            else:
                $sorted = $cats;
                $sorted = array_slice($cats, 0, 8);
            endif;

            echo '<div class="megamenu_icon_list">';
            foreach( $sorted as $cat ) {
                $icon_type = get_term_meta( $cat->term_id, 'getbowtied_icon_type', true );
                if ( $icon_type == 'custom_icon' ) {
                    $thumbnail_id   = get_term_meta( $cat->term_id, 'icon_img_id', true );
                    if ($thumbnail_id)
                        $icon = wp_get_attachment_thumb_url( $thumbnail_id );
                    else
                        $icon = wc_placeholder_img_src();
                    // Prevent esc_url from breaking spaces in urls for image embeds
                    // Ref: https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/23605
                    $icon = str_replace( ' ', '%20', $icon );
                    echo '<a href="'.esc_url( get_term_link( $cat->term_id ) ).'"><img src="'. $icon .'" alt="'. $cat->name .'" /><span>'. $cat->name .'</span></a>';
                } else {
                    $icon = get_term_meta( $cat->term_id, 'icon_id', true );
                    if (!$icon) {
                        $icon = 'thehanger-icons-alignment_align-all-1';
                    }
                    echo '<a href="'.esc_url( get_term_link( $cat->term_id ) ).'"><i class="'. $icon .'"></i><span>'. $cat->name .'</span></a>';    
                } 
            }
            echo '</div>';
            $output = ob_get_contents();
            ob_end_clean();
            return $output;
    }
endif;
```

***/**

Please, can anyone point me in the right direction as to how approach this task?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways, for example in the following way

```php
function woo_product_cat_widget_args( $cat_args ) { 
    if ( is_product_category() ) {
        // Get current category id
        $current_cat_id = get_queried_object_id();

        // Category id = ?, exclude ids ??
        $cat_id_1_exclude_ids = array( 1, 2, 3, 4 );
        $cat_id_2_exclude_ids = array( 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 );
        $cat_id_15_exclude_ids = array( 16, 18 );

        if ( !empty( $current_cat_id ) ) {
            // Excludes ID's based on current category id
            // Extra check that the variable name (array) exists
            $exclude_ids = isset( ${'cat_id_' . $current_cat_id . '_exclude_ids'} ) ? ${'cat_id_' . $current_cat_id . '_exclude_ids'} : '';

            if ( $exclude_ids ) {
                $cat_args['exclude'] = $exclude_ids;
            }
        }
    }

    return $cat_args;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_categories_widget_args', 'woo_product_cat_widget_args', 10, 1 );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_categories_widget_dropdown_args', 'woo_product_cat_widget_args', 10, 1 );
```

Comment: I've added this to functions.php in my active theme, edited the IDs $cat_id_31_exclude_ids = array( 39, 43, 44 );  , removed the next two lines (for new) and went to test it out. It doesn't seem to work. I open category with the ID 31 and categories 39, 43 and 44 are still shown in the widget. WP does not report any error in the code.

Comment: Tried the updated version. Now it shows a critical error in categories with the ID left to the =. In this case those are 1, 2 and 15. I also tested the version I added in my post and shoot, you were right, even that one doesn't seem to work. Back to the square one, I guess.

Comment: I updated and tested my code, now it certainly work!. If the original code you added doesn't work (which it does for me) then the problem is elsewhere. 
Can you try my last modified code again? I added an extra `woocommerce_product_categories_widget_dropdown_args` filter

Comment: I tested the new, updated version. Still no luck. I looked at the page source code and found this for the widget area where the categories are shown `<aside class="widget woocommerce widget_product_categories_with_icon">` so I thought doing this `add_filter( 'widget_product_categories_with_icon_args', 'woo_product_cat_widget_args', 10, 1 );` or this `add_filter( 'woocommerce_widget_product_categories_with_icon_args', 'woo_product_cat_widget_args', 10, 1 );` would help but none of those did work.

Comment: I apologise. You are correct, I should have first tested the code I added in my original post. My mistake. I was able to test a plugin called Hide Categories On Shop Page. It works however it hides the category it general, not in a way I need. The plugin has this file wc-hide-categories-on-shop-page.php and I'm going to try to see whether I'll be able to apply the code you suggested.